# The ring of Laurent polynomials over a Noetherian ring is Noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian

In the Wikipedia  about [Larent polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_polynomial#:%7E:text=The%20ring%20of%20Laurent%20polynomials%20is%20a%20subring%20of%20the,Noetherian%20(but%20not%20Artinian).&text=group%20of%20rank-,.,a%20commutative%2C%20cocommutative%20Hopf%20algebra.), there is this result:

```
The ring of Laurent polynomials over a field is Noetherian.
```

I was wondering if would it be enough for us to have Laurent polynomial over a Noetherian ring? For example, I think $\mathbb Z[X,X^{-1}]$ is Noetherian.

**Question**: Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring. Is $R[X,X^{-1}]$ Noetherian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $R$ is a Noetherian ring then $R[X]$ is a Noetherian ring (by Hilbert's basis theorem). Since $R[X,X^{-1}]$ is the just the localization of $R[X]$ at the multiplicatively closed set $\{X^n: n \geq 0\}$, it too must be Noetherian.

Comment: @DietrichBurde -- I am confused by your comment, I think you suggesting that I am ghc1997, but I'm not sure why?